# Angular 2, unable to patch value to form controls

Tags: forms, angular, validation, firebase

In my angular 2 app, I have an edit assignment component which loads when user clicks on edit button. It displays a form and fills all form controls with already existing values from firebase database which user can then edit. It loads all the values in the form controls when I click the edit button for the first time. Then if I go back or navigate to any other link and then click on the edit button again the form controls do not patch values from firebase database.

The images below will help you understand the problem better:

I click on the edit button first time everything works fine
[image]

Then if I go back to some other link and then return by clicking the edit button again the form does not patch form controls with values from firebase database.
[image]

I am validating my form like this

```
constructor(
  private _routeParams: ActivatedRoute,
  private _db: AngularFireDatabase,
  private _fb: FormBuilder,
  private _uploadService: UploadService,
  private _getAsnService: GetAssignmentService,
  private _editAsnSvc: EditAssignmentService,
) { 
  console.log("in constructor");
  this.validate();
}

ngOnInit() {
  console.log("in init");
  this.getRouteParams();
  this.assignment = this._getAsnService.getAssignment(this.asnDetailKey); // this.assignment is FirebaseObjectObservable retrieved from firebase DB
  this.setInputValues();
  this.getCourses();
  this.validate();
}

validate() {
this.form = this._fb.group({
  course: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
  batch: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
  subject: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
  name: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
  description: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
  dueDate: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
  });
  this.today = new Date().toJSON().split('T')[0];
}

setInputValues() {
  this.assignment.subscribe(asnDetails => {
  console.log("setting values"); // <----- These are the values you see in console
  this._assignment = asnDetails;
  console.log(this._assignment); // <----- _assignment contains all values but form controls are unable to patch them
  this.form.get('course').patchValue(this._assignment.course);
  this.form.get('batch').patchValue(this._assignment.batch);
  this.form.get('subject').patchValue(this._assignment.subject);
  this.form.get('name').patchValue(this._assignment.AsnName);
  this.form.get('description').patchValue(this._assignment.AsnDesc);
  this.form.get('dueDate').patchValue(this._assignment.dueDate);

  this.batches = this._db.list('/batches/' + this._assignment.course);
});
}
```

Thanks

*** Edited ***

I removed the setInputValues method and did the validation inside the validateForm method (i changed name from validate to validateForm) by passing asnDetails to it as told by @developer033

```
 ngOnInit() {
this.getRouteParams();
this.assignment = this._getAsnService.getAssignment(this.asnDetailKey);
this.assignment.subscribe(asnDetails => this.validateForm(asnDetails));
this.getCourses();
}

 validateForm(asnDetails) {
this.form = this._fb.group({
  course: [asnDetails.course, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
  batch: [asnDetails.batch, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
  subject: [asnDetails.subject, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
  name: [asnDetails.AsnName, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
  description: [asnDetails.AsnDesc, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
  dueDate: [asnDetails.dueDate, Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
});
this.today = new Date().toJSON().split('T')[0];
this.batches = this._db.list('/batches/' + asnDetails.course);
}
```

I also created a initForm method and call it from constructor to initialize form.

```
  initForm() {
this.form = this._fb.group({
  course: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
  batch: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
  subject: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
  name: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
  description: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
  dueDate: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
});
}
```

I think thats the cleaner way to validate model driven forms dynamically.

Comment: Why you don't simplify it and set all values in `validate()`? In fact, you don't need `setInputValues()`.

Comment: How to do it dynamically ? Do i need to pass assignment object as parameter to validate ? Sorry im new to angular.

Comment: Yes, pass the `assignment` to your `validate()` (also consider renaming this function). Also, the `Validators.compose` isn't needed. See [**this plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/NuCkJ8sK38oXKE9yyA7q?p=info).

Comment: It helped a lot. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `validate()` method actually is wrong. It is initialising the form with default values and with validators which get executed automatically. The name `validate()` is misleading. In your case you create a new form with `this._fb.group()` everytime and you loose all the former values. The first time its just working because the request takes some time and in the meantime your `validate() aka initializeForm()` method did run. I guess in all other cases the request may is cached and so the `setInputValues` is called before your `validate` method. Just move the call to `validate()` before calling the `asnService` and you should be good. Greetings Chris

Comment: Thank you ChrisY. It helped :)